# wpf "emailto" - with attachments

Tags: wpf

I am developing a WPF app in MVVM presentation pattern. I have a grid and I am trying to have an "emailto" hyperlink and when the user clicks that i am trying to export all the data to an excel and open the default email client with a draft new message window(email client could be Lotus/Outlook) and attach the excel as an attachment to the mail. I am able to define a "Mailto" hyperlink and when i click that i am able to open the draft message email window. But i am not sure how to send the excel as an attachment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By sending an Excel file you don't mean generating of this file somehow. Right? So you just need to attach a file.

I always use [Andrew Baker's MAPI wrapper class](http://www.vbusers.com/codecsharp/codeget.asp?ThreadID=71&PostID=1) which seems to be very reliable and has never failed for last 6 years. It's just 18Kb of C# code and it does exactly what you need.

```
var message = new MapiMailMessage(subject, body);
message.Recipients.Add(mailAddress);
message.Files.Add(filePath);
message.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you. But the i dont want to open up a custom UI to send an email. I just want to open up the default mail client interface with a pre composed message.

Comment: @HariSubramaniam, have a look at the source code. It doesn't use any own/custom UI to send email. The *ShowDialog* method launches the default email client with pre composed message. Don't be confused by the method's name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Simple MAPI API](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=2048&zep=SimpleMAPICon/MapiApi.cs&rzp=/KB/IP/simplemapidotnet//simplemapidotnet.zip) to solve your problem:

```
var mapi = new Mapi();
mapi.Logon(IntPtr.Zero);

foreach (var filePath in files)
    mapi.Attach(filePath);

mapi.Send("subject", "body text", true /* show send message dialog to user */);
mapi.Logoff();
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you. But the i dont want to open up a custom UI to send an email. I just want to open up the default mail client interface with a pre composed message.

Comment: That is how it works. A mail client registers itself in Windows as a default mail client. When you invoke `mapi.Send("my subject", "my body text", true)` Windows tells the mail client to open send message dialog with subject `my subject`, body `my body text` and attached files.