# Sharing the current ppt file via email from Powerpoint Add-In application

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, powerpoint

I am developing a Powerpoint Add-In application (C# visual studio), which has a feature to share the current ppt file via email. Could you please give me any suggestion for that? thanks

Comment: So you basically want to send mail? Or do you need more?

Comment: yes, I just want to send email with attached file. And it's good if there is any free library or built-in .Net library?

Comment: Is it acceptable to just delegate it to the user's email client (I.e. pop up a pre-populated email form with the file attached, and the user hits "send")?

Comment: For these "not sure what you're asking questions" sometimes it helps to show what code you have so far (even if it just shows the point at which you are trying to send stuff, 'cause I'm not sure if you want to send a PPT file, the some other file or what)

Comment: Ok, let me update my question. Indeed, I want to share the current ppt file via email.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: how do we know which mail tool the user is using? (e.g., outlook, thunderbird, etc.) and how we can launch this application and fill the subject, body and attachment? Thanks

Comment: As long as the user is using *some* email program, that will be used (the standard email client in windows). To send using this method you don't have to worry about smtp servers etc., as that is preconfigured in the users' mail program already. See the accepted answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114969/wpf-emailto-with-attachments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the built-in `MailMessage` class in .NET. It has a property `Attachments` which you can fill with the attachments of your needs. Get the current file name of the file and use it to fill the `Attachment` class.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a working sample how to set and send the `MailMessage`.

You can get the path of the file currently editing using this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.FullName
```

Don't forget to save it first.

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my question. The application I am developing is a Powerpoint AddIn application. And I do not find out the Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer namespace.

Comment: I am just new to a microsoft application AddIn (like Powerpoint, Word, Excel AddIn). So at the beginning, I think sharing email from the AddIn application is the same as a normal .Net desktop application.

Comment: looks promising. I am checking it out. Thanks @Patrick Hofman

Comment: Your solution works well. But how do I specify the server and port the user is using for his email address?

Comment: See google: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.port(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do I know the server and port of email the user is currently using? E.g., abc@gmail.com --> gmail smtp server. abc@yahoo.com ---> yahoo server, there are tons of email server out there. So I have to list all and make a loop to check?

Comment: You have to use your own